# Getting from Javascript to PHP for Deleting from Database

Tags: php, javascript, get

I have a link that's generated from a entry in a database, and I need to be able to delete that link. I have the DELETE query in my PHP, and a JavaScript confirm that works just fine, but confirming won't activate the PHP query. Here's the code:

JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    function deldoc(docid, docname)
    {
       if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete '" + docname + "'"))
       {
          window.location.href = '<?php echo DIREMPLOYEE;?>?deldoc=' + docid;
       }
    }
</script>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['deldoc'])){ 
    $deldoc = $_GET['deldoc'];
    $deldoc = mysql_real_escape_string($deldoc);
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Documents WHERE docid = '$deldoc'") or die(mysql_error());
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Document Deleted"; 
        header('Location: ' .DIREMPLOYEE);
    exit();
}
```

When I press the OK button on the Confirm popup, it takes me to the Index page, but it's not deleting the document, and it's not giving me an error. Instead, it just tacks the docid onto the end of the directory URL, so it looks like this:

`http://domain.com/employee?deldoc=7`

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: maybe remove your `header('Location...` for debugging reasons.

Comment: Tried that. And thanks for the edit, @Barmar

Comment: You shouldn't be using DROP but DELETE (drop is for tables, columns etc not records).

Comment: maybe your docid is not correct. echo your query and try if it works if you do it directly on your db

Comment: As jeff pointed out, you should be using DELETE, not DROP. ```DELETE FROM Documents WHERE docid = '$deldoc'```

Comment: The docid is correct. I checked that to be sure. The confirm even uses the name of the document, so I know it's choosing the correct one.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a connection to the database before you try running the query?

Comment: Of course. The file that this is own is pulling the documents from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query should be something like this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM Documents WHERE docid = '$deldoc'")
```

**Warning:**

`mysql_` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO`. Also your code is not safe. It's vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: ouch... `mysql_*` + get param in the string... Deprecated + injection

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem You're right, but I can't rewrite his whole code, I'm just trying to fix the issue he's asking about.

Comment: and injection issue is already prevented by mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @steven: which is deprecated, too, and, left to its own devices, flawed, too (charset...)